# MS CRM 2015/2016 auto-numbering

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, auto-increment, id-generation

Any idea about the auto-numbering for the custom entities in MS CRM ONLINE ?

i've already searched on net ,it says that i must develop my own plug-in to handle this thing , or i should create a workflow that will generate ID for the new records.

Help please!
Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to develop it

Answer (score 0):

To do auto_numbering with workflow, I have already used this link to do that :

*http://leontribe.blogspot.com/2010/12/auto-numbering-using-workflow.html*

It shows all steps to create auto_numbering with a workflow. it is based on creating a new custom entity to store values.